# StackOverflowError in Jenkins build after upgrade from LTS 2.19.3 to LTS 2.46.3

Tags: java, jenkins, jakarta-ee, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-cli

I am getting the following StackOverflowError after I upgraded the Jenkins version from LTS 2.19.3 to LTS 2.46.3. I have more than 70 jobs in my Jenkins.  I am getting this error only for 5-6 jobs and all the other jobs are working fine. I don't know what is wrong here. Can you guys please help?

```
Parsing POMs
FATAL: null
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at com.google.inject.internal.DelegatingInvocationHandler.invoke(DelegatingInvocationHandler.java:36)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy71.lookup(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor159.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.google.inject.internal.DelegatingInvocationHandler.invoke(DelegatingInvocationHandler.java:50)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy71.lookup(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor159.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
```

here is my pom file

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.mycompany.mywork.mymodule</groupId>
<artifactId>MyFramework</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<name>My Framework</name>
<description>Framework for a standalone error capturing and storing mechanism</description<parent>
    <groupId>com.mycompany.parent</groupId>
    <artifactId>app-parent</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
<properties>
    <spring-data-jdbc.version>4.3.6.RELEASE</spring-data-jdbc.version>
</properties>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>org.maven.repo1</id>
        <name>Maven Repo</name>
        <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- oracle driver for jdbc -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
        <version>11.2.0.3.0</version>
        <!-- <scope>provided</scope> -->
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- for change capture engine -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.antlr</groupId>
        <artifactId>antlr4</artifactId>
        <version>4.0-rc-1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- <dependency> <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId> <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId> 
        <version>4.5.1</version> </dependency> -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<profiles>
    <!-- Default profile, includes all dependencies so Eclipse does not show 
        compile errors. -->
    <profile>
        <id>default</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>

        <build>
            <resources>
                <resource>
                    <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                    <filtering>true</filtering>
                </resource>
            </resources>
            <plugins>
            <plugin>
                 <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                 <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
                 <version>2.5.1</version>
                </plugin>

                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.4.3</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <junitArtifactName>junit:junit</junitArtifactName>
                        <skipTests>true</skipTests>
                        <includes>
                            <!-- files called unit test are run, these better not use IO -->
                            <include>**/*UnitTest.java</include>
                        </includes>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
        <properties>

        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles></project>
```

Comment: Can you paste that as text rather than an image?

Comment: Jenkins has [a lot](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Aissues.jenkins-ci.org+"StackOverflowError"+"DelegatingInvocationHandler") of bug reports of errors along these lines. Unfortunately there doesn't seem to be any common solution. Some users report that updating to the latest Maven plugin for Jenkins fixed their issue.

Comment: Are they [Maven-style](http://javaadventure.blogspot.bg/2013/11/jenkins-maven-job-type-considered-evil.html) jobs of freestyle using Maven build step?